# Creating site with Jekyllbootstrap in github pages?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I recently created a site using [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/). And my site is up and running in github. In my local directory I have a folder called `_sites`. I changed the contents over there (my editing `index.hmtl` and other files), as per my wish.

I tried running :

```
jekyll --server
```

And I can see all my changes done in my local machine.

But when I commit and push. I couldn't able to see the changes in my site.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have plugins GitHub Pages will not serve your Jekyll powered site automatically.